# Accessing state variable in callback function always undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

Trying to understand how state works when returning a callback function. `useWeb3React` is active (logs in the useEffect), but account in `getAccountMatch` is always undefined. I've tried adding a callback with dependencies, adding a ref to the account item, but always get a null account value when using the `getAccountMatch` function.

Any help pointing out what I'm missing would be helpful. I'm assuming that `getAccountMatch` is using the initial values which is why account isn't available when it runs, but unsure how to fix.

```
  const useTest = (): any => {
  const { account } = useWeb3React();

  const getAccountMatch = async () => {
    // no matter when this is called, account will remain undefined
    if (!account) return;
    alert("account is ready");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // This will update as expected
    console.log("account logs here when active");
  }, [account]);

  return [getAccountMatch];



 const Connect = () => {
    const { account } = useWeb3React();
    const { textAccountMatch } = useTest();
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        account && textAccountMatch();
      }}
    >
      Connect
    </button>;
  };
```

I've managed to get this working by passing in a reference of account and doing `textAccountMatch(account);` and using that as opposed to the state variable in `useTest`. Feels like I *shouldn't* have to do this though...

Comment: could you add the component in which this is being called?

Comment: Added a sample component to show the issue

Answer (score 0):

Store the account value in a useState

```
const useTest = (): any => {
  const { account } = useWeb3React();
  const [value, setValue] = useState()

  const getAccountMatch = async () => {
    if (!value) return;
    alert("account is ready");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // This will update as expected
    console.log("account logs here when active");
    setValue(account)
  }, [account]);

  return [getAccountMatch];
}
```